# Passing EnvFunctionCall an instance address from C/C++

Tags: clips

I'd like to call a CLIPS deffunction from C++ and pass it an instance. I am using the standard CLIPS 6.30 distribution (not any C++ bindings). I am currently working with the following definitions:

```lisp
(defclass CFAM (is-a USER))

(deffunction drop-cfam (?cfam)
    (send ?cfam delete))

(definstances KNOWN_THINGS
    (cfam-1 of CFAM))
```

I invoke the function `drop-cfam` from C++ by passing it the instance address for the instance that I'd like to delete.

```cpp
void* instancePtr = EnvFindInstance(clipsEnv,NULL,"cfam-1",false);
assert(EnvValidInstanceAddress(clipsEnv,instancePtr));

ostringstream args;
args << instancePtr;

cout << "Calling 'EnvFunctionCall for 'drop-cfam' w/ args: "<< args.str() << endl;

DATA_OBJECT callResult;
const bool callFailed = EnvFunctionCall(clipsEnv,"drop-cfam",args.str().c_str(),&callResult);
assert(!callFailed); // results in abort

const bool droppedCfam = static_cast<bool>(DOToInteger(callResult));
assert(droppedCfam);
```

An abort occurs on the specified line, while the terminal window displays:

```
Calling 'EnvFunctionCall for 'drop-cfam' w/ args: 0x274c290
[MSGFUN1] No applicable primary message-handlers found for delete.
[PRCCODE4] Execution halted during the actions of deffunction drop-cfam.
```

Initially, this suggested that perhaps it is incorrect for me to be passing (what I believe is) an instance address to `drop-cfam`. However, testing in the terminal suggests that this should not be the problem:

```
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (instances)
[initial-object] of INITIAL-OBJECT
[cfam-1] of CFAM
For a total of 2 instances.
CLIPS> (drop-cfam (instance-address [cfam-1]))
TRUE
CLIPS> (instances)
[initial-object] of INITIAL-OBJECT
For a total of 1 instance.
```

The Advanced Programming Guide (v6.30) states that arguments should be passed to `EnvFunctionCall` as strings. That section (4.1.10) does not specify any restrictions on data types passed to `EnvFunctionCall`, and does not reference any other sources that specify lexical forms for data types. I am unsure if I even *can* pass an instance address via `EnvFunctionCall` at this time or if my design needs to be modified to avoid it.

**EDIT / Workaround**

There was an issue in my design where I assumed that my system required an instance address when it did not. The desired behaviour of this question can be achieved by passing the instance name to `EnvFunctionCall` rather than the address as follows:

```
EnvFunctionCall(clipsEnv,"drop-cfam","[cfam-1]",&callResult);
```

Which has the same behaviour as:

```
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (drop-cfam [cfam-1])
TRUE
```

I will still accept any answer that demonstrates how to pass an instance address in a lexical form or describes why the terminal version accepts both instance names and instance addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no lexical representation in CLIPS for C pointers (which includes instance, fact and external addresses), so you can't directly specify them. This applies both to the API calls which parse string arguments as well as terminal commands and CLIPS code. During execution addresses can be dynamically bound or returned from function calls and these values can be passed to functions. That's  how the instance address is computed from the terminal in your example function call "(drop-cfam (instance-address [cfam-1]))". You can evaluate this same type of expression using EnvEval rather than EnvFunctionCall:

```
EnvEval(clipsEnv,"(drop-cfam (instance-address [cfam-1]))",&callResult);
```